# Get already imported module in current file by name

Tags: python, python-import

I am studying `sklearn` and I write a class `Classifier` to do common classification. It need a `method` to determine using which Estimator:

```
# Classifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

class Classifier(object):
    def __init__(self, method='LinearSVC', *args, **kwargs):
        Estimator = getattr(**xxx**, method, None)
        self.Estimator = Estimator
        self._model = Estimator(*args, **kwargs)

    def fit(self, data, target):
        return self._model.fit(data, target)

    def predict(self, data):
        return self._model.predict(data)

    def score(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
        return self._model.score(X, y, sample_weight=None)

    def persist_model(self):
        pass

    def get_model(self):
        return self._model

    def classification_report(self, expected, predicted):
        return metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted)

    def confusion_matrix(self, expected, predicted):
        return metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted)
```

I want to get Estimator by name, but what **xxx** should be?
Or is there a better way to do this?
Build a dict to store the imported module?  but this way seems not so good..

Comment: I don't get it. Where is your import? Can you pass the __xxx__ as a parameter?

Comment: @sobolevn  import at the top, `from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression` and so on

Comment: Do you want to support dynamic module imports?

Comment: @sobolevn  As you see, the `Classifier Estimator` from different module of sklearn, program don't know which from `linear_model ` or `svm `. Using `dynamic import` mean I need a dict to record which `class` from which `module`

Comment: For many reasons it is better to give the actual class `LogisticRegression` as parameter, rather than the string version.

Comment: I think so too. If you can't know in advance which module you will use, it is better to work with class itself.

Comment: @PascalvKooten Could you explain the reasons? I really want to know the detail.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is advised to simply use the class directly as an argument.

You will never have to worry about it as a string: you can compare `LinearSVC is LinearSVC`, and compare it to something else.

Think of it like accepting an integer as argument, then converting it to a string to use it: does that make sense? You can just simply require a string.

Proposed code:

```
class Classifier(object):
    def __init__(self, model = LinearSVC, *args, **kwargs):
        self._model = model(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can then do:

```
myclf = Classifier(..., estimator = LinearSVC, ...)
isinstance(myclf._model, LinearSVC)
```

#### As per the comment:

You can then also initialise a dict at start like:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

str_to_model = {'LinearSVC' : LinearSVC}

class Classifier(object):
    def __init__(self, model = "LinearSVC", *args, **kwargs):
        self._model = str_to_model[model](*args, **kwargs)
```

It's cleaner to work with a `KeyError` (the string/model does not exist, and you're aware since you did not define them), than to check `globals`, sounds pretty nasty!

Comment: Because I need to build a `Classifier`  by a html form. A user can choose the method,  that's why I use string.

Comment: You can use `model.__name__` to get `LinearSVC`.

Answer (score 0):

Built in function [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) does the trick: you can check that `globals()['LogisticRegression'] is LogisticRegression` returns `True`.

ADDENDUM

- Safe: nothing 'nasty' can happen by evaluating `globals()[method]`
- Efficient: overhead is negligible with respect to `some_method_dict[method]`
- Simple: `globals()[method]` is just the shortest answer to the question.

If this is pythonic or not, I don't know, but the `globals()` builtin is there to be used, so why chose more complicated solutions?

To be explicit,

```
Estimator = getattr(..., method, None)
```

can be implemented as

```
Estimator = globals().get(method)
```

if the `None` return is preferred to a `KeyError` exception if `method` was not imported.

Comment: It just like magic....I just wonder is this way safe and efficient? I need to instantiate this `Classifier` in many different module.

Answer (score 0):

There are two build-in functions may help you: `globals` and `locals`, both of the two return a dict of the current symbol table.

you code could be `Estimator = globals()[method]` or mv the estimator keys to `__init__` and use `Estimator = locals()[method]`